# In-App Purchases With Apple

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app

I wonder if anyone have this problem before

I have an IOS App at App store . when user buy the App and later on wanted to have the same App on other device user have such as Ipad the App take hem to App store where he should Enter Credit card 3 digits number and then App store charge hem something like 0.30$ . i have no idea what's that's for . for every new device user have App store charge hem with that amount of money

How i can fix this so that if user buy the app once then he can use it with all user devices without been charged for anything as long as user using the same App store account he buy from in the first place